# Matlab Simscape vs Simulink vs PDE-Toolbox/Ansys/Comsol

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape, ansys, comsol

I found a Matlab Simscape example simulating a dynamic linkage. Additionally there's also a Simulink blockdiagramm included and I know how Simulink works/solves the underlying mathematical model. But I don't know if Simscape is just an Animation of the Simulink solutions or if Simscape solves the dynamical model/equations itself. It seems to me, like there is some kind of interface from Simscape to Simulink, so this leaves me wondering where exactly are the differences between those two Tools?

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283707/matlab-versus-simulation-products-such-as-ansys-and-comsol) comparing them already, but it still leaves the exact differences open. It seems to me like Simscape is some kind of mix between Simulink and Ansys/Comsol, but where does it differ exactly? Can Simscape also solve PDEs, or do I need the PDE Toolbox for that? Or does it just solve ODEs? Does it use the same solvers as Simulink?

Do I also need to derive the exact dynamical equations for a Simscape simulation or can I just specify the kind of problem I'd like to have solved (like Euler-Newton or something)?

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all, simscape is a fully self encompassed toolbox so you don't need the PDE toolbox to run it.

Moving on to the larger question, simscape differs from simulink in how it handles data signals and ports. Standard Simulink flows data from between blovks using ports. The blocks are executed in a relatively linear fashion.

Simscape however uses something called physical ports which don't execute in the same linear fashion. In terms of software comparison, it would be more similar to [Amesim](https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/global/en/products/simcenter/simcenter-amesim.html) or the modelling Language [Modelica](https://www.modelica.org/). The blocks used in simscape contain an enseble of PDEs, linear equations and expressions. The physical ports define how these equations connect and depend on each other. Each time step in then typically solved/converged numerically.

Obviously there are many more differences, however this is what seemed to be most relevant to what you mentioned in the question. More details on Simscape as well as some very good webinars on the product can be found on the [simscape product page](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simscape/features.html)